# How to extract data out of a file in c++?

Tags: c++, file

I have a file consisting of "time elapsed" information as:

```
"D:\p\prototypes\performance\target_win64-vc10sp1\CMakeFiles\3.0.20140226\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
(DoLinkOutputFilesMatch target) -> 
      C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(990,5): warning MSB8012: TargetPath(D:\projekte\.\CompilerIdC.exe) does not match the Linker's OutputFile property value (D:\p\\prototypes\performance\target_win64-vc10sp1\CMakeFiles\3.0.20140226\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.exe). This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Link.OutputFile). [D:\p\prototypes\jperformance\target_win64-vc10sp1\CMakeFiles\3.0.20140226\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj]

        1 Warning(s)
        0 Error(s)

    Time Elapsed 00:00:01.50
Build succeeded.

"D:\p\prototypes\performance\target_win64-vc10sp1\CMakeFiles\3.0.20140226\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
(DoLinkOutputFilesMatch target) -> 
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(990,5): warning MSB8012: TargetPath(D:\projekte\.\CompilerIdCXX.exe) does not match the Linker's OutputFile property value (D:\p\CD_8570w\robotic_applications\prototypes\jenkins_performance\target_win64-vc10sp1\CMakeFiles\3.0.20140226\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.exe). This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Link.OutputFile). [D:\p\CD_8570w\robotic_applications\prototypes\jenkins_performance\target_win64-vc10sp1\CMakeFiles\3.0.20140226\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj]

    1 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:01.54
Build succeeded.

    0 Warning(s)

    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:02.06
```

Now i want to extract only the last "Time elapsed" data i.e "02.06" out of this file using c++ program. Currently what i am doing is something like as follows:

```
   std::string line;
   std::string token = "Time Elapsed ";
   std::ifstream file(my_file_path);
   while(getline(file, line)){
       if (line.find( token)!= std::string::npos) {
             // do some stuff
        }
     }
```

What happening is i get all "Time elapsed" value but i just need the one at the end of file. So, kindly suggest me how can i get this value.

Comment: Keep the value in a variable, and overwrite it every time. At the end that will contain the last value

Comment: Or try using function similar to fseek() in cstdio

Comment: If you use fseek(fileptr,-5,2); it will go to the position exactly before 02.06

Answer (score 1):

You can store the value you find and process with your `if (line.find(token)` in a variable outside of the while statement. When the while statement is finished (therefore you processes the whole input), you will only have the last result in that variable.

Comment: please elaborate with an example.

Answer (score 1):

As a complement to @cookiesoft answer:

```
std::string line;
std::string token = "Time Elapsed ";
std::ifstream file(my_file_path);

std::string lastValue; // << Add this

while(getline(file, line)){
    if (line.find( token)!= std::string::npos) {
        // do some stuff

        lastValue = your_computed_value; // << Add this
    }
}

// Now lastValue contains the last processed value
```